# seleccionar una posición de una matriz 1 (asignado) y comprar si es igual al valor que se encuentra en la misma posición en una matriz 2 (registrado)

Tags: python, python-3.x

soy bastante nueva programando en python y estoy tratando de hacer un código que tome dos matrices del mismo tamaño y primero compare si los valores de la fila 0 de la primera matriz sea igual a los valores en la mima posición en una matriz 2, esto por medio de un ciclo for, pero hasta ahora lo que he intentado me arroja un error en la parte del if "list indices must be integers or slices, not list".

```
asignado = [[1, 98, 11], 
           [2, 86, 14], 
           [3, 99, 11], 
           [4, 89, 12], 
           [5, 89, 12]]
registrado = [[1, 100, 10], 
             [2, 86, 10], 
             [3, 97, 15], 
             [4, 93, 15],            
             [5, 94, 12]]
```

```
for i in asignado:
  for j in registrado:
    if asignado[i][0] == registrado[j][0]:
      eficiencia= int (((asignado[i][2]-registrado[j][2])/asignado[i][2])*100)
      print('Para punto #' + asignado[i][0] + '=' + round(eficiencia) + '%')
    eficiencia=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Pasa que `i` y `j` no son valores enteros como supones, sino que filas completas. Fijate en esto:

```
for i in asignado:
  for j in registrado:
      print(i, j)
```

produce:

```
[1, 98, 11] [1, 100, 10]
[1, 98, 11] [2, 86, 10]
[1, 98, 11] [3, 97, 15]
...
[5, 89, 12] [3, 97, 15]
[5, 89, 12] [4, 93, 15]
[5, 89, 12] [5, 94, 12]
```

Como `i` es una lista, el primer valor (columna 0 de la matriz) es `i[0]`.

Nota: esto demuestra el valor de usar nombres significativos para las variables, ya que destaca el contenido.

Nota: No uses concatenación de cadenas para armar un texto. Tu código tiene un error, ya que aplicación concatenación de cadena y entero, lo que es inválido.

Para formar una cadena, usa formato de edición. A partir de Python 3.8, puedes usar `f-strings` que te permite escribir directamente una expresión dentro de una cadena encerrandola entre "{ }".

Reescribiendo el código con variables bien nombradas y arreglando la edición, tienes:

```
for fila_asignado in asignado:
  for fila_registrado in registrado:
    if fila_asignado[0] == fila_registrado[0]:
      eficiencia= int (((fila_asignado[2] - fila_registrado[2])/fila_asignado[2])*100)
      print(f'Para punto # {fila_asignado[0]} = {round(eficiencia)} %')
    eficiencia=0
```

produce:

```
Para punto # 1 = 9 %
Para punto # 2 = 28 %
Para punto # 3 = -36 %
Para punto # 4 = -25 %
Para punto # 5 = 0 %
```

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta <3